# Express - Check if session exist

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am setting up my NodeJS & Express App, using Passport for authentication with Google Sign In and Login. Everything works very well when working on localhost.

The signin process works very well, and I can see the user information attached to req.user contains all user information.

However, right after that, when calling any route, req.user is undefined

I try desperately, to check if any session doesent exist to redirected that, on my login page, but it gives me some error based on `Unexpected token`

index.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const passport = require("passport");
const GoogleStrategy = require("passport-google-oauth20").Strategy;
const app = express()
const port = 5000

// if user is not logged-in redirect back to login page
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   if (req.session.user == null){
   res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/login');
   }   else {
    next();
   }
});

app.use(
  session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  cookie: { httpOnly: false, secure: false, maxAge: 60 * 1000},
  saveUninitialized: false,
     })
  )

passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy({
  clientID: "process.env.clientID",
  clientSecret: "process.env.clientSecret",
  callbackURL: '/auth/google/callback',
},
async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
  const existingUser = await User.findOne({
    providerId: profile.id,
  })
  if (existingUser) {
      return done(null, existingUser);
  }
  const user = await new User({
    provider: profile.provider,
    providerId: profile.id,
    displayName: profile.displayName,
    
  }).save()
  done(null, user);
 })
)

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (obj, done) {
  done(null, done);
});
```

My error :

```
ERROR  Error in fetch(): request to http://localhost:3000/login failed, reason: read ECONNRESET

  at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1461:11)
  at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:400:28)
  at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:475:9)
  at Socket.emit (events.js:400:28)
  at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
  at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
  at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)
```

Thank you

Comment: A couple things.  First `ECONNRESET` sounds like a network connection problem or perhaps the browser page is going away before your request finishes.   That's not your server returning an error back to the client.  Second, If this request is coming from client-side Javascript, please show that client code because it could be that it's not correct for including cookies which would cause your server to never see a session.

Comment: @jami00 I think it only comes from this code i added because when i erase the `check session` function, all working well, thats weird...

Answer (score 3):

For starters, move this:

```
// if user is not logged-in redirect back to login page
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   if (req.session.user == null){
   res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/login');
   }   else {
    next();
   }
});
```

to be after this:

```
app.use(
  session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  cookie: { httpOnly: false, secure: false, maxAge: 60 * 1000},
  saveUninitialized: false,
     })
)
```

There will NEVER be a `req.session` until AFTER the session middleware runs so any code that tries to use `req.session` must be after the session middleware.

Also change this:

```
if (req.session.user == null)
```

to:

```
if (!req.session || !req.session.user)
```

So the code is safe if `req.session` doesn't exist.

Comment: i move that but i always got same thing

Comment: @Thestrike95 - Change `if (req.session.user == null)` to `if (!req.session || !req.session.user)` and see if that makes a difference. If you have no session, then `req.session` will be undefined so you can't test for `req.session.user` without throwing an error.